# Get Input Value on the same page with PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Well, first i'm new in PHP. Is there a way to get the input value from a existing input on the page on page load with php and pass it to a variable?

For example i have this input: `<input type="text" name="g_id_p" id="example1" value"foo">`

I want to do something like this: `$got_it = $_GET['g_id_p'];`

Sorry again if i wrote my code wrong, im noobie on this. Hope to someone help me.

Comment: Is this variable used in the same page or another page?

Comment: I want to use that variable on the same page.

Comment: Yes... you do it using the code you are showing.  What isn't working?

Comment: $got_it = $_GET['g_id_p']; it's not working.

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, op wants to get the value on the same php page - ie, not after the form has been submitted but rather get the 'initial' or 'default' value as specified by the value="" tag

Comment: You can set the `method="GET"` on `form` tag. However all the other inputs within the form will also need to be accessed by `$_GET`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't really get an associated value of an input tag within the same PHP page but what you can do is set the value of a variable beforehand.

What I mean is, create an array that will store all the values of all the input tags.

```
$inputValues = array();
$inputValues['g_id_p'] = 'foo';
```

Then when you have the tag later on just echo it from the PHP var.

```
<input type="text" name="g_id_p" id="example1" value="<?php echo $inputValues['g_id_p']; ?>">
```

As you can see, we aren't really 'getting' the value that you set but the end result is the same.

Answer (score 1):

First, would be great to know what method is the form. (GET or POST)

Then after know what type of method you could call it in PHP:

**METHOD POST:**

```
<input type="text" name="g_id_p" id="example1" value"foo">

$variable = $_POST['g_id_p'];
```

**METHOD GET:**

```
<input type="text" name="g_id_p" id="example1" value"foo">

$variable = $_GET['g_id_p'];
```

If you haven't defined a method, in html the tag for a form is:

```
    <form>
<!-- Here goes your input and some stuff -->
    </form>
```

Then it would be something like:

```
    <form name="form_name" class="form_class" id="form_id" method="TheFormMethod" action="ThePageThatExecutesThisForm">
<!-- Here goes your input and some stuff -->
    </form>
```

TheFormMethod can be post, get, delete, put.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check if the values is set [isset()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php), where you want to use the variable do:

```
if(isset($_GET['g_id_p'])){
   //your code
}
```